# Detecting previous bundle version with Wix Burn

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.10

I'm trying to detect what the version number for a previously installed bundle is. However burn does not seem to find it, although it appropriately detects that it is going to do a major upgrade.

This is what the relevant parts of my bundle xml looks like:

```
<?define BUNDLE_UPGRADE_CODE=my_upgrade_code_guid?>

<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">

  <Bundle UpgradeCode="$(var.BUNDLE_UPGRADE_CODE)" DisableModify="yes" ...>

    <util:ProductSearch UpgradeCode="$(var.BUNDLE_UPGRADE_CODE)" Variable="PreviousVersion" />

    <BootstrapperApplicationRef ... />

    <Chain>
      <ExePackage Id="my_exe_package".../>
      <MsiPackage Id="my_msi_package" .../>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

The thinking being that ProductSearch should detect any product using the upgrade code and place the version number in the variable `PreviousVersion` for later use. However, burn does not seem to detect any existing product with this upgrade code, instead it always sets the version to "`0.0.0.0`". Here are the relevant parts of the log file (somewhat edited for clarity):

```
...: Detect begin, 2 packages
...: Product or related product not found: {my_upgrade_code_guid}
...: Setting version variable 'PreviousVersion' to value '0.0.0.0'
...: Detected related bundle: {previous_bundle_product_code}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.0.0, operation: MajorUpgrade
...: Detected related package: {previous_msi_product_code}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.0.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
...: Detected package: my_exe_package, state: Absent, cached: Complete
...: Detected package: my_msi_package, state: Absent, cached: None
...: Detect complete, result: 0x0
...: Plan begin, 2 packages, action: Install
...: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: my_exe_package
...
...: Planned package: my_exe_package, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
...: Planned package: my_msi_package, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
...: Planned related bundle: {previous_bundle_product_code}, type: Upgrade, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: Uninstall, rollback: Install, dependency: None
...: Plan complete, result: 0x0
```

If I "manually" query for products using the upgrade code using `MsiEnumRelatedProducts` I also cannot find it, whereas querying for the upgrade code from the msi package properly returns the msi product.

**Are my expectations off?** In this case, I can get away with querying for the msi upgrade code instead as that version will always be the same for me. I am more interested in why this does not work as I thought it would.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ProductSearch` and `MsiEnumRelatedProducts` look for MSI packages, not Burn bundles. A custom bootstrapper application gets the version of the existing bundles in its `OnDetectRelatedBundle` callback.